# httpd command line not recognized

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, windows-7, httpd, httpd.conf

I've got Apache 2.2 running on Windows 7.
However, the command line does not work - if I type in httpd it says:

> httpd is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch file.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Add directory with `httpd.exe` to PATH environment variable.

Comment: Or type the full path to httpd.exe as part of the command.  Tedious, but works if the PATH can't be changed.

Comment: @All, sorry This site doesn't allowing me for posting the comment of the @gelraen answer.so i posted in answer block. @gelraen I also facing same problem,so you suggested to set path in environment variables. can you suggest me where will find `Httpd.exe` directory.